# Minimax alpha-beta pruning depth

Tags: artificial-intelligence, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I have implemented a connect 4 AI to play in a tournament for my class. I have implemented a depth limited minimax with alpha-beta pruning. We are allowed to give one depth to give as an argument for the tournament. My program will make a move, then another student will make a move, and this continues until there is a winner. It is also a modified connect 4 in which the entire 42 spots in the 6×7 game board are filled, and every 4-in-a-row is a point, and the most points wins.

My question is about the alpha-beta pruning. Our moves have to take "about 1 second", so anything under 2 seconds should be fine. Running my program without alpha-beta pruning allows a move about 1.3 seconds or less at depth 6. Depth 7 is unacceptable. Now, with alpha-beta pruning, can I guarantee that I can change my depth to go deeper? I know on average that it will let me go deeper, but I believe on the worst case nothing gets pruned, and I would exceed the time limit. Is this correct?

Comment: Btw... Your program ran a heck of a lot faster when I debugged it in c#... Are you sure it is only running at 50'000 nodes per second? O.o When I ran it, it got up to 1'000'000 nodes...

Comment: I wouldn't think my heuristic would change it that much, but I have a rather long heuristic now that checks for 2 in a rows, 3 in a rows, ect. Basically it checks 12 if statements in 4 for loops. So about 50 if statements to create a utility value. I wouldn't think that would be that much overhead though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This IS correct: in the worst-case scenario, alpha-beta is just as slow as minimax.

Bit there is a really small chance for that to happen. To optimise alphabeta and prevent that problem, search "move ordering alpha beta" on google.

If you have to stay inside a time limit, I suggest to use iterative deepening (search with depth 1, 2, ..., x). That should not be a problem due to the exponential explosion. If your program runs out of time, just play the move you figured out with the previous searchdepth.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't possible. It is a tournament ran by the professor, so once it's my programs turn to move, the professor immediately runs my program, and if it hasn't made a move in less than 2 minutes, my program basically forfeits.

Comment: @user2587878: Yes, thats how it's handled in chess tournaments too (More or less). The stuff I mentioned (iterative deepening) is really easy to implement. Then you just create another thread that runs a timer. As soon as this other thread sees that the program has reached the time limit, it stops the minimax calculation and returns the previous depth result. Works all fine.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. Problem with that is my program is already running slow for some reason, and iterative deepening is even slower. While theoretically it is slower by a constant, that constant could lose me another level of depth.

Comment: @user Sure, it COULD, but since a ply less takes 1/7 of the time, it is not to be expected. Even if you can't make it to your max depth due to that, it will always at least guarantee the second best depth, as well as staying inside of time limit. Otherwise, you would always have to search a ply less, as some kind of safety bound, so it is a win in any case. If you want, send me your algorithm (xxliolauxx@gmail.com), and I'll have a look at it and see if I can do some performance optimisation (really, even my noob-chessengine searches to depth 7!)